# Proving an equality for exponential operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and $A \in \mathcal L(E).$ If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} A_n = A$ then show that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left (I + \frac {A_n} {n} \right )^n = e^A.$$

**My attempt** $:$ Let $x_{\alpha,n} = \binom {\alpha} {n} \frac {A_{\alpha}^n} {\alpha^n}.$ Since $A_{\alpha} \to A$ as $\alpha \to \infty$ it follows that $\|A_{\alpha}\| \to \|A\|$ as $\alpha \to \infty.$ Hence there exists $M \gt 0$ such that $\|A_{\alpha}\| \leq M,$ for all $\alpha \in \Bbb N.$ So $$\|x_{\alpha,n}\| \leq \binom {\alpha} {n} \frac {M^n} {\alpha^n} \leq \frac {M^n} {n!}.$$ Also $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {M^n} {n!} = e^M$ and $\lim\limits_{\alpha \to \infty} x_{\alpha,n} = \frac {A^n} {n!}.$ Thus by DCT we have $$\lim\limits_{\alpha \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x_{\alpha,n} = \lim\limits_{\alpha \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom {\alpha} {n} \frac {A_{\alpha}^n} {\alpha^n} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {A^n} {n!} = e^A.$$ This shows that $$\lim\limits_{\alpha \to \infty} \left (I + \frac {A_{\alpha}} {\alpha} \right )^{\alpha} = e^A$$ as required.

Does my attempt make sense? Please check it.

Thanks for your time.